# groovy function parameter in batch script

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i need to use a groovy function parameter in a batch script in a jenkinsfile.
i tried several possibilities including everything listed here: https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4 , but i am not able to find a solution for accessing the content of the variable "example" in my batch script.

```
def function(example) {
...
bat label: '', script: '''@echo off
...
...
mkdir "some path\\"value of example"\\some additional path"
'''
...
}
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. `""" ... ${example} ... """`

Comment: if you mean it like that: mkdir """some path\\${example}\\some path"""
that didnt work

Comment: what does it mean `didnt work` ? any errors ?

Comment: no errors, the created folder was named ${example}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
"""some path\\${example}\\some path"""
```

Note: you are using single triple quotes in your example. This will not work and your variable will not be used. You need to use triple double quotes for that `"""`

Comment: you are my savior!